# what is a good editor besides eclipse for printing clojure code?

Tags: clojure

I like clojure and use textmate/sublime text but every time I print out the source code, it is not syntax colored and the lines are all messed up. Is there an online/offline editor that does the job? I don't want to load up eclipse everytime I want to print something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've printed code from Emacs before quite successfully. `M-x print-buffer` ought to do it.

You might also be able to paste your code at [refheap](https://www.refheap.com) and click the 'maximize' link and print from there, but it doesn't word-wrap.

Refer to http://stuff.mit.edu/people/lucylim/emacs_print_syntaxhighlighting.html for Emacs printing with color.

Comment: hmmm... emacs still can't give the syntax highlighting... and i can't  find the maximise link on the page - or do you mean the maximise browser button?

Comment: After you paste, the maximize button is on the top right of the paste box.

Comment: Ahh! Gotcha! You have to 'paste' twice, ctrl-v then click the 'paste' button.